# Three.js - Question about eyeSep in StereoCamera

Tags: javascript, three.js, stereo-3d, webxr

so I'm creating a WebXR app with Electron and Three.js. I'm using the StereoCamera class to simulate the stereo effect necessary for VR headsets. Now the StereoCamera class offers a property called eyeSep which mimics the user's IPD (Interpupillary distance). With my app I'm allowing users to adjust that eyeSep value through the use of a range slider but I'm running into a slight problem.

As the ipd value DECREASE the 2 images being rendered move FARTHER apart
[image]

Then as the ipd value INCREASE the 2 images being rendered move CLOSER together
[image]

So my question shouldn't it be the opposite? As IPD decreases the images should move closer together and if IPD value increases the images should move farther apart?

Then here is the javascript code I use to change the eyeSep value

```
  this.updateIPD = function(){
    stereo.eyeSep = parseFloat(new_IPD);
  }
```

Then here is the code for the HTML slider:

```
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse-ipd-slider">
        <div id="collapse-container" class="card card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-4">
                <div class="w-75">
                  <input type="range" class="custom-range" id="customRange11" value="0.064" min="0.040" max="0.080" step="0.001">
                  <p>IPD: <span id="value"></span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Perhaps maybe I'm the one that has it all backwards. I could really use someone who understands the Stereocamera class in three.js or has worked on stuff like this before. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit irritated by your question since a WebXR app does not need to use `StereoCamera`. This type of camera is actually totally unrelated to the WebXR device API.